# How to solve question marks in string

Tags: c#, unicode, internationalization

My website creates ads from events and I use the eventful api to fetch the data I need for my website.
After I have gotten the data from the api the description property (which is a ordinary string) has a lot of question marks.
The ad is in swedish and 2 question marks appear at spaces where it is suppose to be a vowel.

the text displays as this:

> Vill du l??ra dig mer om tron, l??ra dig hur du studerar Bibeln mer effektivt och hur du till??mpar det i vardagen? D?? ??r Lifecenter Evening College n??got f??r dig!
>   P?? Lifecenter Evening College studerar du p?? kv??llstid, t.ex. vid sidan av andra studier eller arbete.??Det ??r d??rf??r ett bra s??tt f??r dig som inte kan l??sa p?? bibelskola p?? heltid.
>   ??
>   Lifecenter Evening College erbjuds under tv?? l??s??r, f??rsta ??ret innefattar kurserna:

If you browse to the original site you can read the description as it should be in swedish. Anyone who knows something about this problem?
this is the original Event site.
[Link to original ad](http://eventful.com/events/lifecenter-evening-college-/E0-001-071381566-8?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic)

If I look at the property in when I'm in the controller it shows the same "wrong" description as it does in the web page. But I don't know how to fix it.

The website is written in c#.

Comment: Thank you. I found the issue. when i i used a reader i converted to ASII charset. I got it working just as i wanted by switching to Encoding.UTF8. 

So now it works. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a character set issue.
Characters that are not part of the ASCII set get turned into question marks: "l??ra" comes from "lära".
If you tell us what language you are writing in, it'd be easier to give concrete advice on how to fix it.

Comment: Im writing in c#. The language the text is in is swedish

Comment: I found the answear. Changed encoding.ASII to encoding.UTF8 and that solved it. Thank you for your help. I wouldnt have found it if it werent for your answear. 
Thanks again.